# Fastest way to ArrayFlatten a 2D array of 2D arrays, both for Sparse and Dense

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I am using Mathematica 12 and want to know what is the fastest way to transform a 2D array of 2D arrays both for dense and sparse arrays. I remember looking for this a few versions of *Mathematica* ago, when `ArrayFlatten` was not that good. Since then I have been using option one below (which I found somewhere here, but I can't find the question anymore - it had other suggestions as well). But a quick check shows that for `SparseArray`s that is not the case anymore. Is there anything better than `ArrayFlatten`

Also, why is the `SparseArray` version of 3 not the same as the other two, unless I make them dense?

```
dim = 5; eles = 50;
sparse = Table[
   KroneckerProduct[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {eles, eles}], 
    IdentityMatrix[eles, SparseArray]], {ii, 1, dim}, {jj, 1, dim}];
Dimensions[sparse]

{5, 5, 2500, 2500}

RepeatedTiming[
 jSparse1 = 
   Apply[Join[##, 2] &, 
    Table[Join @@ sparse[[All, ii]], {ii, 1, dim}]];]

{0.04, Null}

RepeatedTiming[jSparse2 = ArrayFlatten[sparse];]

{0.0094, Null}

RepeatedTiming[
 jSparse3 = 
   SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{{i_, j_} :> sparse[[i, j]]}, {dim, 
     dim}];]

{0.23, Null}

Dimensions /@ {jSparse1, jSparse2, jSparse3}

{{12500, 12500}, {12500, 12500}, {12500, 12500}}

jSparse1 === jSparse2

True

jSparse1 === jSparse3

False

jSparse2 === jSparse3

False

Normal[jSparse1] === Normal[jSparse2] === Normal[jSparse3]

True
```

And here is the dense version with same conclusion

```
dim = 5; eles = 50;
dense = 
  Table[KroneckerProduct[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {eles, eles}], 
    IdentityMatrix[eles]], {ii, 1, dim}, {jj, 1, dim}];
Dimensions[dense]

{5, 5, 2500, 2500}

RepeatedTiming[
 jDense1 = 
   Apply[Join[##, 2] &, 
    Table[Join @@ dense[[All, ii]], {ii, 1, dim}]];]

{1.251, Null}

In[5]:= RepeatedTiming[jDense2 = ArrayFlatten[dense];]

{0.61, Null}

RepeatedTiming[
 jDense3 = 
   Normal[SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{{i_, j_} :> 
       dense[[i, j]]}, {dim, dim}]];]

{2.3, Null}

Dimensions /@ {jDense1, jDense2, jDense3}

{{12500, 12500}, {12500, 12500}, {12500, 12500}}

jDense1 === jDense2

True

jDense1 === jDense3

False

jDense2 === jDense3

False

Max[jDense1 - jDense2]

0.

Max[jDense1 - jDense3]

0.

Max[jDense2 - jDense3]

0.
```

and again the third version produces a result that apparently is not identical with the other two, though numerically they seem to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Applying `` SparseArray`SparseArraySort `` to `jSparse3` will make it the same as `jSparse1` and `jSparse2`.  Also notice that `jSparse1 == jSparse3` returns `True`.

`SameQ` (`===`) compares the internal structure of the `SparseArray`s, which are the `"ColumnIndices"`, `"RowPointers"`, `"NonzeroValues"`, and `"Background"` properties. At least, that's the defining properties for vectors and matrices. (I am not totally sure about higher order tensors.)

The problem is that not every *Mathematica* `SparseArray` is stored in the standard compressed row storage (CRS) format. But `` SparseArray`SparseArraySort `` converts to the standard format.
The standard requires the column indices in each row to be ascending; `jSparse3` violates this:

```
row = RandomInteger[Length[jSparse3]];
rp1 = jSparse3["RowPointers"][[row]];
rp2 = jSparse3["RowPointers"][[row + 1]];
OrderedQ@jSparse3["ColumnIndices"][[rp1 + 1 ;; rp2]]
```

> False

Sorting the column indices is not for free, that's why `Mathematica` sometimes suppresses the ordering. But that makes it also hard to work with such sparse arrays, a further reason why `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` should be avoided.

Comment: I didn't know that. So, is the compressed row storage (CRS) format something like the equivalent to a packed array, but for `SparseArray`s? That is, should one always aim to have their `SparseArray`s in CRS format? Also, does CRS require an NxN `SparseArray`?

Comment: "That is, should one always aim to have their SparseArrays in CRS format? " --- Yes. But not necessarily for performance reasons but because virtually all algorithms for sparse matrices demand that (_they_  usually do that for performance reasons, though ;) ). So whenever you send some sparse arrays data to some expernal programme, make sure that it is sorted correctly. "Also, does CRS require an NxN SparseArray?" --- No. Matrices of any size (hence also non-square matrices) are supported. But there is no analogous standard for higher order tensors. Here _Mathematica_ does its own thing.